# Pipeline on Devops with SonarQube gets "Could not find target branch"

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I tried a Pull Request and i triggered the pipeline before complete de merge, but I got the followed log

> {"task":{"id":"AXuKvrZjTmGb5CxwFPXc","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AXuKvrZYTmGb5CxwFPXb","componentKey":"Portal.API","componentName":"Portal.API","componentQualifier":"TRK","status":"FAILED","submittedAt":"2021-08-28T03:12:39+0000","submitterLogin":"myemail@email.com.br","startedAt":"2021-08-28T03:12:39+0000","executedAt":"2021-08-28T03:12:39+0000","executionTimeMs":30,"logs":false,"errorMessage":"Could
> not find target branch 'null' in
> project","hasScannerContext":true,"pullRequest":"198","warningCount":0,"warnings":[]}}

[image]

anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

For me, I find that the branch here should be set to be the same (name) as your PR's target branch name:
[image]

and then, when your PR is successfully scanned, it will show like this
[image]

Comment: usage of links to images rather than directly uploading them to answer
the answer is not clear

Comment: @A.Rashad Thanks for your reminding~ I tried just now but found need 10 reputations then could directly put image in answer. Not kind enough for green hand here LOL.

Comment: keep up the great work, and thanks for contributing. Here, you have now 11 points :)

Answer (score 0):

In `Prepare Analysis Configuration` task, you can try to add the following Properties.

```
sonar.pullrequest.vsts.instanceUrl = https://dev.azure.com/org/
sonar.pullrequest.vsts.project= Projectname
sonar.pullrequest.vsts.repository =reponame
```

[image]

This will help sonarqube to determine the Pull Reuqest in Azure DevOps.